# pygments + bootstrap: highlight shell code with dark background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pygments

I am rendering code snippets via pygments and markdown in my little [static blog generator](https://github.com/oz123/blogit) and I am having a problem with the pygments and twitter bootstrap.

Here is my problem:

I want code snippets to be highlighted with [dark-solarized theme for pygments](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/honza/solarized-pygments/master/solarized.py). I downloaded it to:

`/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/styles`

Testing works as expected:

```
$ pygmentize -l python -f html -O full,style=solarized -o ./snippet.html ./test.sh
```

This produces an html file which looks as I expected:

[image: hoora! pygments work]

hoora! pygments work! Now, this is how the code is highlighted in my blog post:

[image: fucked up]

bummer ... this looks bad ...

If I comment out:

```
<link href="/media/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The syntax highlighting works as expected:

[image: messed up]

So, my question is: how do I make twitter-bootstrap play along with pygments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, after a while of thinking how this question can and if it should be written.

For the benefit of others, the solutions was to define the color of the `pre` element:

```
pre { line-height: 125%; color: #93a1a1;}
```

This now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Override Bootstrap CSS for Pygments Syntax Highlighting](https://alcidanalytics.com/p/pygments-bootstrap-css-conflict):

```
/* fix bootstrap conflict with Pygments */
.codehilite pre { white-space: pre;
                  border-radius: inherit;
                  display: inherit;
                  background-color: inherit;
                  border: inherit;
                  color: inherit;
                }

/* fix conflict with other sytlesheets */
.codehilite .m { margin: inherit; }
```